# Data columns on reputation page with repeated numbers

Tags: support, reputation

On the [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation), what does the first column represent?

> [image: reputation]

What are these numbers [3,2,3,2,3,2,16,...] for, highlighted in the image?

Comment: Don't know what 16 is, but 1 is an accept, 2 an upvote and 3 a downvote. They are event IDs

Comment: @Bart: 16 is ApprovedEditSuggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the ID of the type of "vote" you received:

```
Id Name                  
-- --------------------- 
1  AcceptedByOriginator  
2  UpMod                 
3  DownMod               
4  Offensive             
5  Favorite              
6  Close                 
7  Reopen                
8  BountyStart           
9  BountyClose           
10 Deletion              
11 Undeletion            
12 Spam                  
15 ModeratorReview       
16 ApproveEditSuggestion
```

See the VoteTypes table on the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/110415/vote-types?opt.textResults=true).

To be complete, the second column is the ID of the post the "vote" applies to and the third is the amount of reputation gained (minus rep is a negative gain) from the "vote".

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers correspond to the type of event that caused the reputation change (i.e., whether it was due to an upvote, downvote, bounty, etc.).

That page is mostly defunct though, with everything on it being covered by the regular account reputation page.